# How to check if string starts with value containing #, tab, and maybe space?

Tags: bash, scripting

In my `bash` script, I want to check whether a string starts with `#    modified:` or `#    new file:`.  In both instances, the character after # is a tab.  In the latter instance, the character between "new" and "file" is a space.

I tried:

`if [[ $outline == "#\tmodified:*" ]]; then`

and

`if [[ $outline == "#   modified:*" ]]; then` (hit actual tab after #)

But neither worked.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With any POSIX shell:

```
tab=$(printf '\t') # or tab='   ' # (a real tab character)
case $outline in
  ("#${tab}modified:"*) ...
esac
```

With `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash`:

```
case $outline in
  ($'#\tmodified:'*) ...
esac
```

or:

```
if [[ $outline = $'#\tmodified:'* ]]; then...
```

The key is:

- `*` must not be quoted, otherwise it's taken literally.
- `\t` is only expanded in the `$'...'` type of quote (or by `printf` in the format argument)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash regex string matching operator `=~`:

```
outline="#  modified: Jan 10 2015" # or
outline="#  new file: hello.sh"
if [[ $outline =~ ^#\   (modified|new file): ]]; then
    echo match
else
    echo no match
fi
```

Note that both white spaces before `modified` instances in the code, and the white space before `new file` are tabs. the white space inside `new file` is a regular space.

*(Edited to match either of the two formats.)*